# How to pass multiple parameters to lambda function

Tags: angular, lambda, openlayers

i would like to know please how can i pass some parameters to the labmda function `this.func`?

i want to be able to pass three parameters including the event, and display its contents using `console.log`

**code**:

```
this.map.un('pointermove',this.func)

private func = (e)=>{
    console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: this.map.on('pointermove', (event) => this.func(event, param1, param2));

private func = (e, p1, p2) => {
    console.log('Event:', e);
    console.log('Param1:', p1);
    console.log('Param2:', p2);
};

Comment: @BR75 can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.map.on('pointermove', (event) => this.func(event, param1, param2));

private func = (e, p1, p2) => {
  console.log('Event:', e);
  console.log('Param1:', p1);
  console.log('Param2:', p2);
};
```